# Which network packet format to use

Tags: java, network-programming

I'm designing a system which has two components: A base station running a Java application of my design, and an Arduino running a program also of my design. The Arduino and the base station communicate wirelessly to exchange sensor data. As it stands, I am communicating by sending single bytes back and forth which isn't ideal. A single byte can only represent between 0 and 255 so I am losing sensor sensitivity by scaling from 2048 to 255. To solve this problem, I want to design a network packet. I understand how packets work, but I don't know which format to use for my packet. Is there some standard format I should use or is this kind of thing entirely left up to the programmer?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you're communicating using UDP? In which case, the format is entirely up to you. You may want to consider inserting a header and footer to bookend the packet allowing you to verify that the entire packet was received. It may also be worth including some way of testing that the packet was received intact, such as including a check-sum of the data but that may be more complicated than your needs require.

Finally, I'd also recommend including an incrementing integer so that you can ignore (or resort) packets that arrived out of order.